# Json data into hive heap size error

Tags: json, hive, apache-nifi

I am working on nested json data which i got from facebook using nifi. i have creating a table in hive and loading the data using the command.

```
CREATE TABLE abmediaanalysis (id string, posts struct< data:array<struct< message:string, shares:struct< count:int>, id:string, reactions:struct< data:array<struct< name:string,id:string>>, paging:struct< cursors:struct< before:string,after:string>, next:string>>, likes:struct< data:array<struct< id:string>>, paging:struct< cursors:struct< before:string,after:string>, next:string>>>>, paging:struct< previous:string,next:string>>, feed struct< data:array<struct< permalink_url:string,message:string,id:string>>, paging:struct< previous:string,next:string>>)ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe';

load data local inpath '/home/10879/facebook1480479682880.json' overwrite into table abmediaanalysis;
```

i have also added the jar file json-serde-1.3.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar,
but when i am using **lateral view explode** to print all the columns, i am getting [java heap size error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hc5YH.png). i have also increased the heap size but still same error

```
select id,posts_message,posts_share_count,posts_id,feed_data_permalink_url,feed_data_message,feed_data_id,reaction_data_name,reaction_data_id,posts_likes_data_id from abmediaanalysis
LATERAL VIEW explode(posts.data.message)MSG as posts_message
LATERAL VIEW explode(posts.data.shares.count)CT as posts_share_count
LATERAL VIEW explode(posts.data.id) I as posts_id
LATERAL VIEW explode(feed.data.permalink_url) PU as feed_data_permalink_url
LATERAL VIEW explode(feed.data.message) MSG as feed_data_message
LATERAL VIEW explode(feed.data.id) I as feed_data_id
LATERAL VIEW explode(posts.data.reactions) NM as posts_reactions_name
LATERAL VIEW explode(posts_reactions_name.data.name) NM as reaction_data_name
LATERAL VIEW explode(posts_reactions_name.data.id) NM as reaction_data_id
LATERAL VIEW explode(posts.data.likes) I as likes_data_id
LATERAL VIEW explode(likes_data_id.data.id) I as posts_likes_data_id;
```

when i tried to print two or three columns instead of showing 616 records its showing 15625 records approx. 
Can anyone help with this issue 
Is there a chance to load the above json data directly from nifi into hive table? if so can you tell me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have added another approach, which may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If I may suggest you another approach to just load the whole `JSON` string into a column as `String` datatype into an external table.

e.g.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE json_data_table (
    id String,
    json_data String
    )   
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u0001' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STORED AS TEXTFILE 
LOCATION '/path/to/json';
```

Use [Hive `get_json_object`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-get_json_object) to extract individual columns. E.g.

If json_data column has below JSON string

```
{"store":
  {"fruit":\[{"weight":8,"type":"apple"},{"weight":9,"type":"pear"}],
   "bicycle":{"price":19.95,"color":"red"}
  },
 "email":"amy@only_for_json_udf_test.net",
 "owner":"amy"
}
```

The below query fetches

```
SELECT get_json_object(json_data, '$.owner') FROM json_data_table;
```

returns `amy`

In this way you could extract each `json` element as column from the table.